# How to get previous SKU's Amount?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way I can get previous SKU data in present row in SQL Server:

| Date | Fol | SKU | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 44 | 1 | 2 |
| 01-01-2021 | 44 | 2 | 3 |
| 05-03-2021 | 45 | 1 | 4 |
| 05-03-2021 | 45 | 2 | 5 |
| 08-06-2021 | 46 | 1 | 6 |
| 08-06-2021 | 46 | 2 | 7 |
| 13-08-2021 | 47 | 1 | 8 |
| 13-08-2021 | 47 | 2 | 9 |

Expected

| Date | Fol | SKU | Amount | Previous Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 44 | 1 | 2 | --------- |
| 05-03-2021 | 45 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 08-06-2021 | 46 | 1 | 6 | 4 |
| 13-08-2021 | 47 | 1 | 8 | 6 |
| 01-01-2021 | 44 | 2 | 3 | --- |
| 05-03-2021 | 45 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 08-06-2021 | 46 | 2 | 7 | 5 |
| 13-08-2021 | 47 | 2 | 9 | 7 |

I've tried lag function but it's not resulting as expected

| Date | Fol | SKU | Amount | Previous Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 44 | 1 | 2 | --------- |
| 01-01-2021 | 44 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 05-03-2021 | 45 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 05-03-2021 | 45 | 2 | 5 | 4 |
| 08-06-2021 | 46 | 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 08-06-2021 | 46 | 2 | 7 | 6 |
| 13-08-2021 | 47 | 1 | 8 | 7 |
| 13-08-2021 | 47 | 2 | 9 | 8 |

Thanks!

Comment: How is the order in you table maintained?

Comment: What have you *researched and tried* so far? Show us your attempt please.

Answer (score 3):

The window functions are well worth your time to get comfortable with them

```
Select * 
      ,PrevAmt = lag(AMOUNT,1) over (partition by SKU order by date)
 From YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]